# Chromecast/Miracast local live stream from camera

Tags: c#, camera, chromecast, live, miracast

I want to get a live stream (local camera) on a chromecast or miracast receiver through a C# application.

Do you know any solution to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster

Comment: Yes but it isn't for live streaming